# scraping google maps data in bulk using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i am a web scraping newbie, i want to scrape google maps in bulk, currently i am scraping only titles of leads. i want to scrape other info like location and ratings and i also want to do it in bulk so i can not click on every lead and extract so i want to get info just from the results i get from searching

currently i am using this code.

```
from learnpanda import get_coordinates_for_state
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os

os.system('cmd /c "cls"')

US_Cities = []

ques = input("Do You Want to enter cities or use default cities(Press E for Entering And D For Default): ")
flag = True
while flag:
    if ques == "E":
        citieses = input("Enter The Cities (Type finish When You Are Done): ")
        if citieses == "finish":
            flag = False
        city_check = get_coordinates_for_state(citieses)
        if (city_check == None) and (citieses != "finish"):
            print("Enter A Valid City")
        else:    
            US_Cities.append(citieses)

    elif ques == "D":
        US_Cities = ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Phoenix"]
        flag = False
    else:
        print("invalid input: Press E for Entering And D For Default")
        ques = input("Do You Want to enter cities or use default cities(Press E for Entering And D For Default): ")

print(US_Cities)
chrome_path = "chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

output = []

def load_companies(url, driver,city):
    print("Searching in", city.replace("+"," "))
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    keepScrolling=True
    while(keepScrolling):
        divSideBar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')
        divSideBar.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        divSideBar.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        html =driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html").get_attribute('outerHTML')
        if(html.find("You've reached the end of the list.")!=-1):
            keepScrolling=False

try:
    for city in US_Cities:
        if " " in city:
            city = city.replace(" ", "+")

        url = f"https://www.google.com/maps/search/christmas+tree+lots/{get_coordinates_for_state(city)}/data=!3m1!4b1"
        load_companies(url, driver,city)
        lead_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'hfpxzc')
        for lead in lead_list:
            lead = lead.get_attribute('aria-label')
            output.append(lead)

    output = list(set(output))
    for h in output:
        print(h)

except Exception as e:
    print("Trying To resolve: ",e)
```

i have made a get_coordinates_for_state function which gives me coordinates of places to make url for google maps, this code only scrape titles, i want to scrape every info, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

- Wait until you find the title, so that it scrapes the rest of the information. This is to ensure the page is fully loaded.
- You can check out the sample code below on how to do it.

```py
 try:
        # Searching for the title
        title = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/\
                    div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1')))
        title = title.text
        print(f'Found "{title}"... extracting the rest of the data')

        # If the title is not found
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        print('Could not find the title!')
            driver.refresh()

    # if company title is found, scrapes rest of the data
    try:
        company_category = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/\
                div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/span/button')

        company_category = company_category.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        company_category = 'NA'

    # rest of the fields you want to scrape
```

Comment: How could just waiting allows us to scrape other info? please explain

Comment: The title is one of the elements in the page, If we wait until the title element is found, rest of the [elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) like company category, address, etc can be easily extracted.

Comment: can you please make the whole code and share it to me, it will be very very helpful, please share it after testing